# Adding payment to websites, testing local with certificat, FindPrivateKey

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment

I'm trying to set up a payment system in my web applications.

So far, i've been instaling certificats, programming C#, but there is something in between that i don't understand.

I'm supposed to find a private key with the FindPrivateKey tool...(i found it, in \Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys without the FindPrivateKey tool)

And give the rigths to my AppPool user ( i'm just testing local so... i don't know) to use the key... i guess...

They suggested me these links :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702621(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732026.aspx

http://www.dotnetnoob.com/2011/01/how-to-give-iis-access-to-private-keys.html

http://benoit808.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/cryptographicexception-the-handle-is-invalid/

After reading them, i was even more confused.

1. What is FindPrivateKey tool ?
2. I'm i not supposed to be able to use certificats if i'm testing on localHost ?

Comment: What type of payment system are you trying to implement? There are many many regulations in that space.  You may be best buying an API from someone like Stripe or PayPal to handle that functionality for you.

Comment: Yeah it's CT-Payment for me

Comment: I might just ask them to guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is FindPrivateKey tool?

In order for your web application to access the private key, it needs access to the file containing the private key.  The point of the tool is to help you find the file so you can right-click on it and assign permissions to the service account associated with your web application.  If you know where the file is then you don't need it.

### I'm not supposed to be able to use certificates if I'm testing on local host?

Depends what the certificate is for.

If we are talking about the SSL certificate that is being used to secure your web site, the domain name of your site must match the *subject* of the certificate; `https://localhost` won't work.  It has to have a proper domain name.  You can work around this by assigning the domain name your loopback address via your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)), e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 www.TheNameOnMyCertificate.com
```

...after which you could access your (local) site using `https://www.TheNameOnMyCertificate.com`.

If we are talking about some other certificate, e.g. a client certificate that your application has to use in order to talk to a third party payment service, then that is totally different.  In most cases you can use the certificate without any issue.

Comment: Opening visual studio as administrator also helped